# How to hide glowing Text appear on saving VS Code File

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsgQ9.png)

Anyone knows what is that 6X glowing text on the right top corner, It appears automatically whenever I saved the file in VS Code editor and also when I press a few commands too.

Actually, when I clicked `ctrl + s` one time, it is like 1x, If I pressed `ctrl + s` two times it's 2x and it keep on increasing.

I don't want it to appear. How to hide?

Comment: That must be from one of your extensions.  You could run the `Bisect` command to figure out which one it is.

Comment: Hi @mark , thanks for answering but How I can use ```Bisect``` in vs code. Could you plz explain me?

Comment: Hi, @Mark thank you so much. After going through Bisect it works and I found out the error and it is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

I simply run the Bisect command and it solved my error by disabling one of the extensions that caused this problem.

Comment: You should include what extension it was in your answer.

Comment: Sure, I will add that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this was caused by the Power Mode extension. Disable it and be happy.

Comment: Yes, True thanks But I already figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks not a bad idea but annoying af, when your text becomes misaligned.