# VS Code showing a counter after typing any character

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCODE is showing a counter after each key is typed. I've looked around some extensions but appears that is an internal VSCODE configuration. I don't know exactly which config is. Please, help me, it's messing my code.

[image]

Comment: There was just this question yesterday.  It is caused by some extension.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303329/how-to-hide-glowing-text-appear-on-saving-vs-code-file?noredirect=1#comment126036955_71303329

Comment: Thanks, Bisect has solved my problem.

Comment: This problem was caused by the Power Mode extension. Disabling it this inconvenience disappears.